# How to scrape the rating and the Date on tripadvisor with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some informations (comments, dates, ratings) from [this hotel on tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g60982-d87016-Reviews-or15-Hilton_Hawaiian_Village_Waikiki_Beach_Resort-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html#REVIEWS)

Here's my script so far :

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import random


root_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g60982-d87016-Reviews-or'
urls = [ '{root}{i}-Hilton_Hawaiian_Village_Waikiki_Beach_Resort-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(5,20,5) ]

comms = []
notes = []
dates = []


for url in urls: 
    results = requests.get(url)

    #time.sleep(20)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='oETBfkHU')

    for container in commentary:

        comm  = container.find('q', class_ = 'IRsGHoPm').text.strip()

        comms.append(comm)


        date_tag = container.find("span", class_="_355y0nZn").text.strip()

        dates.append(date_tag)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'dates' : dates
    })



#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

And here's my output :

[image: output]

I'm not surprised, the `date_tag` isn't quite well specified but I can't see how to pick the right text.

Here's the html :

[image: date]

The "March 2020" has no class at all so I thought if I specify `container.find("span", class_="_355y0nZn").text.strip()` it will work but no it isn't.

And last thing, I don't lnow how to ick the rating, let's see the html :

[image: rating]

As you can see, ther eis not text at all. I think the rating work with `ui_bubble_rating bubble_50` where `50` is the rating (5). How to scrape that ? I never saw this kind of structure before.

Any ideas ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to get the date value

```
date_tag = container.find("div", class_="_1O8E5N17").text 
date_text,date_value = str.split(date_tag,':')
```

I had to use an extra line of coding for converting bs4.element.ResultSet to string

```
comm1 = str(container.find("div", class_="nf9vGX55").find('span'))
rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1))
rat1 = (str(rat))[2]
rating.append(rat1)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have advices on how to get ratings as well ? :)

Comment: Maximum rating is 50. Under class 'nf9vGX55' find span class name and use last 2 digits as the rating value. Example ui_bubble_rating bubble_50 = 50, ui_bubble_rating bubble_40 = 40

Comment: I will try by myself but I would still like to have your code, just in case ! :)

Comment: @DouglasFalcon - check the latest code. Hope you got the answer to both questions

Comment: The part with ratings work for you ? I obtained "none".

Comment: Hmm it works, but it's when I append to my `notes = []` with `notes.append(rating)` then it return nothing. Maybe it's because it return a list ?

Comment: I displayed using print(rating) and it is providing a list with values '[50]','[40]' etc

Comment: Weird, me it print only one value : ['50'] so there is a shape conflict when I build the database.

Comment: I find out where was the problem. I forgot to delete my old code for `notes` so I guess there was a conflict ! Thank you a lot for your help. Upvoted and marked. Have a nice day sir :)

Comment: By the way, do you have an idea how to transform this ['50'] into a integer 5 ? For further analysis. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226359/discussion-between-jethen-and-douglasfalcon).

Comment: Welcome. Let me try to get a single digit as 5 or 4

Comment: rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1)), rat1 = (str(rat))[2], rating.append(str(rat))

Comment: That's doesn't seems to work but maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1)),rat1 = (str(rat))[2],rating.append(rat1)   this should work at any cost

Comment: Yeah it work ! Awesome ! Thank you you're nice :) Upvoted. Don't forget to edit your original post for the ratings !